# Debezium connector inserting kafka key as avro?

Tags: apache-kafka-connect, debezium

I am looking for a debezium mysql connector to stream CDC records to kafka with key as **string** (not avro for key) and value as avro record. By default it is making key as avro record. Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can try to set `key.converter` to `org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter` and `value.converter` keep set to the Avro one.

Or you can use the JSON converter as it also serializes to text.

Comment: You can find more details on the Avro configuration in the [Debezium documentation](http://debezium.io/docs/configuration/avro/). As Jiri is saying, then just specify one of the other converters for the key.

Comment: This is a good suggestion in deed as the key will be a string but schema registry usage for MS SQL Server connector from Debezium is still on beta and using AVRO converter on it will stop rewriting the DELETEs as of today.